# Display Suggestion List on html Form

Tags: php, html, forms

anyone know how to display suggestion list on php / html form?

i dont know the name. but thats i know.

for example : http://www.brandedwatch.co.id/shopping-cart

when you fill kota tujuan form (city) on thats site.

if you fill jakarta on the form, its will display list simillar to jakarta word from database.

how to display this if my code :

```
<form action="doShip" method="post">
City : <input type="text" name="city">
</form>
```

thanks

Comment: like autocomplete? begin city name and show possibilities?

Comment: You can use **Jquery Auto complete**.

Comment: The following links might help you get an overall idea
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-autocomplete-dropdowns-datalist-element
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist

Answer (score 0):

see this is the working example for it may be this will help you a lot

i have used jquery autocomplete

```js
 $(function() {
   var availableTags = [
     "ActionScript",
     "AppleScript",
     "Asp",
     "BASIC",
     "C",
     "C++",
     "Clojure",
     "COBOL",
     "ColdFusion",
     "Erlang",
     "Fortran",
     "Groovy",
     "Haskell",
     "Java",
     "JavaScript",
     "Lisp",
     "Perl",
     "PHP",
     "Python",
     "Ruby",
     "Scala",
     "Scheme"
   ];
   $("#tags").autocomplete({
     source: availableTags
   });
 });
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags:</label>
    <input id="tags">
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```